# Encoding messages returned from API

Tags: python, encoding

I'm communicating with an API and every time I send a request, a list of status messages are returned.  I also have a database that I'm using to log each request.  My db table has a row for each request and I want to have a column for the status messages returned.  There is a total of 15 messages that could be returned by the API and I'm thinking about encoding them so I don't store one giant string of all the messages I receive like 'message1+message2+message3+message4...'

I know I can do something like the following so I could instead store a string like 'A,B,C,D...', but having 15 elif doesn't seem well designed:

```
def request_sent(self,some_list):
    codeCombo = ''
    for message in some_list:
        code = self.get_log_code(message)
        codeCombo = codeCombo + ',' + code
    //store codeCombo in db

def get_log_code(status_message):

    if status_message == 'ORDER_COMPLETE':
        return 'A'
    elif status_message == 'ORDER_FAILED':
        return 'B'
    elif status_message == 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS':
        return 'C'
    elif status_message == 'SYSTEM_BUSY':
        return 'D'
    ...
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

I'm curious to see if a binary approach would work.  If I have a 15 bit binary value that has all its bits initially set to zero.  Each bit would represent a status message.  When the status message appears, the bit value it represents would be switched to one.

Comment: I did think about a dictionary approach.  I'm wondering if I could do some kind of encoding that doesn't result in a string.  Perhaps binary?

Comment: You don't need anything more than that, unless you manually create a messages kind of enumeration and you can return error message codes instead of strings. Dictionaries are efficient though, you should not have any problem with this

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and fastest thing to do is to store all your responses in a dictionary:

```
response_dict={'ORDER_COMPLETE':'A',
               'ORDER_FAILED':'B',
               'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS':'C',
               'SYSTEM_BUSY':'D'}
```

the you can simply modify your function to something like this:

```
def get_log_code(status_message):
    return response_dict[status_message]
```

Answer (score 0):

A classic way is to use a dictionary.

```
messages = {'ORDER_COMPLETE'    : 'A',
            'ORDER_FAILED'      : 'B',
            'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS': 'C',
            'SYSTEM_BUSY'       : 'D'}

if status_message in messages:
    return messages[status_message]
else:
    return '?'
```

Note the check (`if status_message in messages:`) in case there is a message we did not know about.  APIs have a nasty habit giving undocumented messages.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Greg K. said. You could store them as key/value pairs in a dictionary.

e.g.:

```
errors = {
            "ORDER_COMPLETE": "A",
            "ORDER_FAILED": "B",
            "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS": "C",
            "SYSTEM_BUSY": "D"
}

def get_log_code(status_message):
    return errors[status_message]
```